# Why is FunctionalDependency needed for defining MonadReader?

Tags: haskell, monads, ghc, type-systems

I just managed to understand the definition of the class `MonadReader`

```
class Monad m => MonadReader r m | m -> r where
...
```

After reading the document of Functional Dependency in Haskell, now I can understand that `| m -> r` specifies that type variable `r` is uniquely decided by `m`. I think this requirement is reasonable based on the few typical instances of MonadReader I have seen so far (e.g. `Reader`), but it seems to me that we can still define instances like `Reader` even without this functional dependency clause.

My question is why we need functional dependency in the definition of MonadReader? Is this functionally necessary for defining MonadReader in a sense that MonadReader cannot be properly defined without it, or it is merely a restriction to limit the ways how MonadReader can be used so that the instances of MonadReader will all behave in a certain expected way?

Comment: A fun exercise when presented with these questions is to try and write them use a definition without the dep.

Comment: It's not needed for defining `MonadReader`; it's needed for conveniently *using* `MonadReader`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is needed to make type inference work in a way which is more convenient to the user.

For example, without the fundep this would not compile:

```
action :: ReaderT Int IO ()
action = do
  x <- ask
  liftIO $ print x
```

To make the above compile we would need to write

```
action :: ReadertT Int IO ()
action = do
  x <- ask :: ReadertT Int IO Int
  liftIO $ print x
```

This is because, without the fundep, the compiler can not infer that `x` is an `Int`. After all a monad `ReadertT Int IO` might have multiple instances

```
instance MonadReader Int (ReaderT Int IO) where
   ask = ReaderT (\i -> return i)
instance MonadReader Bool (ReaderT Int IO) where
   ask = ReaderT (\i -> return (i != 0))
instance MonadReader String (ReaderT Int IO) where
   ask = ReaderT (\i -> return (show i))
-- etc.
```

so the programmer must provide some annotation which forces `x :: Int`, or the code is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

I think the source of confusion is that in the definition of

```
class Monad m => MonadReader r m | m -> r where
  {- ... -}
```

It is implicitly asumed that `m` contains `r` itself (for common instances). Let me use a lighter definiton of `Reader` as

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader {runReader :: r -> a}
```

When the `r` parameter is chosen you can easely define a monad instance for `Reader r`. That means that in the type class definition `m` should be substitute for `Reader r`. So take a look at how the expresion ends up being:

```
instance MonadReader r (Reader r) where -- hey!! r is duplicated now
  {- ... -}                             -- The functional dependecy becomes Reader r -> r which makes sense
```

But why do we need this?. Look at the definition of `ask` within the `MonadReader` class.

```
class Monad m => MonadReader r m | m -> r where
  ask :: m r -- r and m are polymorphic here
  {- ... -}
```

Without the fun-dep nothing could stop me for defining `ask` in a way to return a different type as the state. Even more, I could define many instances of monad reader for my type. As an example, this would be valid definitions without func-dep

```
instance MonadReader Bool (Reader r) where
--                   ^^^^         ^
--                   |            |- This is state type in the user defined newtype 
--                   |- this is the state type in the type class definition
  ask :: Reader r Bool
  ask = Reader (\_ -> True) -- the function that returns True constantly
  {- ... -}
```

```
instance MonadReader String (Reader r) where
--                   ^^^^^^         ^
--                   |              |- This is read-state type in the user defined newtype 
--                   |- this is the read-state type in the type class definition
  ask :: Reader r String
  ask = Reader (\_ -> "ThisIsBroken") -- the function that returns "ThisIsBroken" constantly
  {- ... -}
```

So if I had a value `val :: ReaderT Int IO Double` what would be the result of `ask`. We'd need to specify a type signature as below

```
val :: Reader Int Double
val = do
  r <- ask :: Reader Int String
  liftIO $ putStrLn r   -- Just imagine you can use liftIO
  return 1.0

> val `runReader` 1
"ThisIsBroken"
1.0

val :: Reader Int Double
val = do
  r <- ask :: Reader Int Bool
  liftIO $ print r   -- Just imagine you can use liftIO
  return 1.0

> val `runReader` 1
True
1.0
```

Aside from being senseless, it is unconvinient to be specifiying the type over and over.

As a conclusion using the actual definition of `ReaderT`. When you have something like `val :: ReaderT String IO Int` the functional dependency says *Such a type might have only one single instance of `MonadReader` typeclass* which is defined to be the one that uses `String` as `r`

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer, but it's much too long for a comment. You are correct that it's possible to define the `MonadReader` class without a fundep. In particular, the type signature of each method determines every class parameter. It would be quite possible to define a finer hierarchy.

```
class MonadReaderA r m where
  askA :: m r
  askA = readerA id

  readerA :: (r -> a) -> m a
  readerA f = f <$> askA

-- This effect is somewhat different in
-- character and requires special lifting.
class MonadReaderA r m => MonadReaderB r m where
  localB :: (r -> r) -> m a -> m a

class MonadReaderB r m
  => MonadReader r m | m -> r

ask :: MonadReader r m => m r
ask = askA

reader
  :: MonadReader r m
  => (r -> a) -> m a
reader = readerA

local
  :: MonadReader r m
  => (r -> r) -> m a -> m a
local = localB
```

The main problem with this approach is that users have to write a bunch of instances.